# MongoDB findOneAndDelete() with multiple conditions (in nested array)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've searched on the internet for this but haven't found a solution.

Problem : I want to delete character (one whole object in characters array).

Criteria: `_id="612d0ba09403d0224b55cb6d"` and `id=0`

I'm only able to locate account (whole presented object), but don't know how to locate the specific character in account.

```
User.findOneAndDelete()({ _id: "612d0ba09403d0224b55cb6d" }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) console.error('Removing character error: ', err)
            else console.log('foundChar', data)
})
```

```json
{
    "_id": "612d0ba09403d0224b55cb6d",
    "nickname":"tester",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "password":"tester",
    "characters":[ 
       {
        "id": 0,
        "name":"hdfghgfd",
        "skin":"thor",
        "exp": 0,
        "account_id":"612d0ba09403d0224b55cb6d"
       },
       {
        "id": 1,
        "name":"bdfsgfds",
        "skin":"starlord",
        "exp": 0,
        "account_id":"612d0ba09403d0224b55cb6d"
       }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To removing a element from an array you have to use `update` and [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)

From the docs:

> The `$pull` operator removes from an existing array all instances of a value or values that match a specified condition.

So you need this query:

```
yourCollection.updateOne({
  _id: "612d0ba09403d0224b55cb6d"
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "characters": {
      "id": 0
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VpDgc8v6wug)